# how to open and read a file in c++

Tags: c++, xcode, file-io, ifstream

PROBLEM SOLVED! Solution found thanks to Debaug in the comments section. Thank you all for helping.

!!!! Update: I added the function perror() inside my check function and it tells me "no such file or directory". So I am pretty sure that my problem comes from where my file is stored. As said in the comments, the file probably isn't in the projects root directory. However I have no idea how to access the root directory. !!!!

I am new to c++ and to programming in general. My problem is very basic but none of the existing answers found on the web worked for it.

I am trying to open a file stored on my computer and to extract the data from it. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Naming the variables
    float Grade;
    float Total;
    float Grade_In_Percentage;
    ifstream inData;

    // Opening the file
    inData.open("test.txt");

    if(inData.fail())
    {
        cout << "Fail: Cannot open the file" << endl;
        perror(0)
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Extracting the data
    cin >> Grade >> Total;

    // Calculations
    Grade_In_Percentage = Grade * 100 / Total;

    // Display
    cout << "Your grade in percentage is:" << setprecision(7) << Grade_In_Percentage << endl;
    Grade_In_Percentage = ceil(Grade_In_Percentage);
    cout << "round up:" << Grade_In_Percentage << endl;

    if (Grade_In_Percentage < 50)
        cout << "Fail" << endl;
    else if (Grade_In_Percentage >= 60)
            cout << "Need improvment" << endl;
        else if (Grade_In_Percentage > 70)
                cout << "Good" << endl;
            else if (Grade_In_Percentage > 80)
                    cout << "Well done" << endl;
                else if (Grade_In_Percentage > 90)
                        cout << "Excellent" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As a result, I get "Fail: Cannot open the file".

What could I do?

Comment: How do you run the program? From a console? From an IDE? Where is the file `test.txt` located in relation to the executable program? To the projects root directory?

Comment: Did you try using a full pathname? Are you sure it's located in the programs current working directory?

Comment: try using absolute path of the file.

Comment: Hi, I run the program in xcode. On my computer, the text file is in the same folder as my code file "main.cpp". Is that what you mean by "projects root directory"? And if I want to use the full path of the file, how would I write that in c++? Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you are on Mac/Linux, using full path should be something like: `inData.open("/home/username/foldername/test.txt");`. On Windows it should be something like: `inData.open("C:/foldername/test.txt");`

Comment: Hello, the full pathname does not work, I just tried it and still have the same output.

Comment: Are you sure that the file name is `test.txt`? Check the case too.

Comment: Yes, I also have tried to remove .txt from the name but it doesn't make any difference

Comment: Xcode doesn't store the executable in the same location as the project (at least by default, I don't know if there's a way to change that), so you have to use the absolute path. To get the full path of a file, open Terminal and drag the file into the Terminal window. You can then copy-paste it in your code.

Comment: @wohlstad macOS stores the user folders in `/Users/`, not `/home/`.

Comment: On GNU Linux/MacOs, using `realpath [path]` in the shell should return the full path.

Comment: Instead of editing your question with a comment saying that you found a solution, maybe you should actually post an answer that explains what you did with enough details so that future visitors that come here from Google with the same problem can fix it.